# Code Style for OOP

Tags: java, c++, style, style-guide

Здравствуйте.

Посоветуйте книгу по дизайну кода (в приоритете ООП на C++  можно и Java на худой конец).
А то порой откроешь свой код и становиться грустно ...

Answer (score 0):

Саттер и Александреску. "Стандарты кодирования на C++"